# Couchbase Bucket used memory

Tags: couchbase

I am new to couchbase.
I use web console to create new Couchbase bucket with RAM allocated = 100 MB ( for testing only).
The thing I don't understand is : this new bucket has 40MB in-use. 
What is it use for ? 
Can anyone explain me ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's used to hold data to avoid having to wait for disk accesses. See [section 1.3.4](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-introduction-architecture-buckets.html) of the couchbase manual if you want more details.

Comment: Hello, I agree that couchBase have to store data in RAM to avoid access to disk. But the bucket I said above has no data. I've just created it in a minute. So that's the problem I don't understand why it uses 40 MB . Can you tell me . Thank you

Comment: @SummerNguyen: It's using memory because you asked it to. If you don't want it to use 40MB of memory, tell it to use less. It's not like if it uses 0MB now, it can use 140MB later.